# ¿How Glide module in CustomInfoWindow? Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-glide

I am currently using **Glide** to upload images to my app. It works fine until I have to load an image into a CustomInfoWindow. I get a warning that has to do with the problem, also I think it has something to do with the available cache.

**Warning:**

Logcat:

```
W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:5
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 5
W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=508KB, data=376KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=402KB, data=275KB
```

build.gradle,import and class:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-rc1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:19.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:19.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.19'
}
```

**import**

```
import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Point
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat
import androidx.core.view.isGone
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.mappet001.reports.ReportPet
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*
import com.google.firebase.Timestamp
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.google.firebase.firestore.GeoPoint
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_maps.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.form_report.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.reportvisor_maps.view.*
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.File
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList
import kotlin.math.cos
import kotlin.math.sin
```

**Class**

```
    //class InfoWindowAdapter
    inner class CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap(val context: Context) : GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

        override fun getInfoContents(p0: Marker?): View? {
            return null
        }

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        override fun getInfoWindow(p0: Marker?): View? {
            val mInfoView = (context as Activity).layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.reportvisor_maps, null)
            val mInfoWindow: ReportPet? = p0?.tag as ReportPet?

            mInfoView.title_window.text = mInfoWindow?.mTitleReport
            mInfoView.date_ReportVisor.text = mInfoWindow?.mDate
            mInfoView.description_ReportVisor.text = mInfoWindow?.mdescriptionReport
            mInfoView.type_ReportVisor.text = mInfoWindow?.mTypeReport
            try {
                val imageReportVisor = mInfoView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_ReportVisor)
                Glide.with(context).load(mInfoWindow?.mImageReport).into(imageReportVisor) // image
            }catch (e: Exception){
                Log.d("ERRORGLIDE","e: ${e.message}")
            }
            return mInfoView
        }
    }
```

then I call the marker in onMapReady:

```
//marker + infoWindow
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener{
            if (it.isInfoWindowShown){
                it.hideInfoWindow()
            }else{
                it.showInfoWindow()
                zoomMarker(it.position)
            }
            true
        }
```

please help me!

Thanks

Comment: Seems like it tells you exactly what you need to do in the first line of the error? `Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored`

Comment: okay. But I don't understand how to implement @GlideMoule

Comment: Have you read the [README](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/README.md) from github? It looks like it's even more straightforward than the error makes it sound. (I haven't actually used Slide but the documentation makes it look pretty user friendly. :) )

Comment: Oh heck. I just realized that's Java documentation. Sorry, I don't speak Kotlin. :(

Comment: From what I can find, it seems like you just need to add the `@GlideModule` to the class that implements it, and make sure you have the `com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule` and `com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule` imports. Sorry I can't be of more assistance.

Comment: Unused import directive `import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule`

Comment: right now I can no longer compile in Android Studio the problem is this:`A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution`

Comment: Finaly I implement de Module. Realize el post en stackOverflow en español. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/379402/kotlin-como-implementar-correctamente-glidemodule/380292#380292

Comment: Esta chido! Gracias por subir su respuesta! Espero que le ayude aun que sea un poco. :) Le pido que suba su respuesta en este post tambien para que les ayude a las personas que lo busquen aca. Yo lo haria pero usted merece la reputacion

Answer (score 0):

To implement **AppGlideModule** change in **Build.Gradle**:

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'` cambiar a esto:
`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'`

In the **Build.Gradle** add plugin y dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
  kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
}
```

synchronize the gradle.

Add a class called **MyAppGlideModule**:

```
Pakage com.example.NombreApp

import com.bumptech.glide.GlideBuilder
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions
import com.bumptech.glide.signature.ObjectKey

@GlideModule
class MyAppGlideModule: AppGlideModule(){}
```

Before continuing, it is important to mention that if you used Glide as a library, you should comment or delete the import of glide://import com.bumptech.glide.Glide.
Now in the class (YourClass) that you want to use the **AppGlide** implement the module as follows:
`GlideApp.with(context).load(url).into(imageView)`
When finished rebuild the project:

Build -> Rebuild Proyect
source: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3H4ufwNPifk&list=LLC1ePrw-k_QIVOvX-BepTIA)